# complex update query postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got a bunch of ids from table `messages` and I want to update the table `activities`. This is how I imagined my query would work (so you get better idea what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
update activities
set activities.created_at = messages.created_at,
set activities.updated_at = messages.updated_at
from messages
where messages.id in (1,2,3)
activities.trackable_id in (1,2,3)
```

In `activities`, the `trackable_id` is foreign key to the `messages` table. So I need to set the right `created_at` and `updated_at` time in activities table for some messages.

So basically the `activity` table is the copy of `messages` table but only in another format.

How can I update created_at and updated_at in the activities table for some message ids, but using the data from messages table (data being updated_at and created_at)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not seem to join your `activities` and `messages` tables in your where clause. The more correct syntax would be:

```
update activities
set created_at = messages.created_at,
updated_at = messages.updated_at
from messages
where messages.id = activities.trackable_id
  AND messages.id in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: I edited your answer to the working version, but I'll accept as it was just synthax short of the right solution. many thanks